# How do I use LINQ to SQL with stored procedures returning multiple result sets without ORM?

Tags: linq-to-sql

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dditweb/archive/2008/05/06/linq-to-sql-and-multiple-result-sets-in-stored-procedures.aspx

Similar to this link however the project I'm working on **doesn't** use the ORM component of LINQ to SQL (we use it more for quickly generating the ADO.Net interface to the db).

Currently, the pattern we follow is:

```
var result = myDataContext.GetAllCustomersAndOrders();
```

And the stored procedure looks like this:

[image]

Are there extra steps I need to take? Do I need to extend the generated dbml or the data context partial class file?

Hopefully this makes sense... It's a bit difficult to explain and all the examples I've found use the ORM piece of the dbml (dragging and dropping tables onto the dbml designer surface).

Comment: Multiple result sets??  Or multiple rows (i.e. a table)?

Comment: Multiple Result sets.  Stackoverflow isn't letting me include the code.  The stored procedure should contain two lines: return all rows from the customer table and return all rows from the orders table.  Two select statements, one sproc.

Comment: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it. Works like a charm (once you know how to use it)

Comment: Couldn't you just return a JOIN between the two tables as a single result set??

Comment: @marc_s: I'd rather not as that would return a lot of extra data that is not needed (in this case, the customer data would be duplicated for each row of order data).  Plus, I already know how to do that.  I'd much rather find a solution to the stated problem: two or more result sets being returned from the sproc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but i will require creating a partial class for your dbml.

So, if your dbml file is MyLinqToSQL.dbml

- open the dbml designer
- drag the SP onto the design surface
- save
- and then press F7.

This will create a partial class of MyLinqToSQL.cs.

Now...

- open the auto-generated MyLinqToSQL.designer.cs
- copy the access method with the same name as the SP (the one you want to return multiple sets from.)
- Insert this into the body of the partial class in MyLinqToSQL.cs you just created.
- change the name of the method to something at least slightly different
- change the return type from ISingleResult to IMultipleResult.
- decorate your new class with System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ResultType attributes to define your return set types.

All of the resultsets will be returned in a single collection of IQueryable.

You can then use reflection to determine the type of each collection item and then cast them for use.

See http://kishor-naik-dotnet.blogspot.com/2011/12/linq-multiple-result-set-of-procedure.html

Comment: How to decorate class with System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ResultType attributes?

Comment: use '[ResultType(typeof(Employee))]'.  See step 8 in the link above for context.